# IOS Objective C - error while passing parameter between two view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two viewControllers :

RegisterViewController & Register2ViewController

I have a segue from  RegisterViewController to Register2ViewController.

I want to set the value of a the `textfielduser` in  Register2ViewController with a value that the user entered in a the `textfieldemail` in RegisterViewController.

so far here is what i've done.

in `RegisterViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)NextPage:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toRegister2" sender:self];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toRegister2"]) {
        Register2ViewController *controller = (Register2ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.user.text = self.email.text;
    }
```

but when I run and fill the values of textfields in RegisterViewController and go over to Register2ViewController the textfield user is empty, can you help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly passing value to textField, try passing text using NSString. Declare `@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *userName;` in `Register2ViewController`. Then pass value to string like

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toRegister2"]) {
        Register2ViewController *controller = (Register2ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.useName= self.email.text;
    }
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` of `Register2ViewController` ,set string on textField like this `self.user.text=self.userName`. 
Try doing this.

Comment: This was just what I needed, it fixed the problem. Thank you very much my friend

Answer (score 4):

```
controller.user.text = self.email.text;
```

At this time, the `Register2ViewController` is not loaded in the memory yet, that's why you are facing this issue.

Keep a NSString property in `Register2ViewController.h` and set the value of that string here.
Then, in viewDidLoad of `Register2ViewController`, set that string as text of UITextField.

Comment: This seems plausible.  There is a distinct lack of 'M' in the MVC; taking values from the Views is not the way forward.

Comment: I gave +1 to your answer & I accepted the answer of Sushil because it was the most helpful, thank you ^^

Comment: No problem :)
Happy Coding!